# Why do some people have symptoms of salmonella and others not?

Tags: immunology, gut-bacteria

So I was reading from the Mayo Clinic website and they say that typically people with Salmonella have no symptoms, but why?  Why do some people have symptoms and others not?  Salmonella does after all mutate.

Here is an excerpt from the Mayo Clinic Website

> "Typically, people with salmonella infection have no symptoms. Others
>   develop diarrhea, fever and abdominal cramps within eight to 72 hours. Most healthy people recover within a few days without specific treatment."

https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/salmonella/symptoms-causes/syc-20355329

Comment: I removed the "toxins" tag because salmonella doesn't actually secrete toxins like Clostridium. Anyway, why is this fact difficult for you to understand; people have varying levels of immunity to different pathogens. Can you elaborate more on what you specifically want to know?

Comment: Symptoms can also depend on the number and virulence of the Salmonella bacteria you ingest.